# IOS - Migrating storyboard to Xcode 8 resize

Tags: xcode8, xcode-storyboard

I used to have a story board in `Xcode 7.3`, today I started migrating to `Xcode 8` by hand because I want to clean some stuff in this version.

The problem that I faced is that in the `storyboard` when I change the device type the content of the view controller scene is not adjusted to the phone.

[image]

This is an example:[image]

The above is the same size as the `storyboard` in `Xcode 7.3`, actually Copy & Paste the View Controller Scene.

When I change the size to the next device I get this:[image]

Now I have a space in the right. I'm using `Auto Layout`.

So I don't know what changed in this version or what do I need to do in order to make my `storyboard` fits on all iPhones sizes.

What I would need to see is if I change to a bigger phone then everything will auto fit on the new screen. Thats the way was working with Xcode 7.3.

> Any advice?